# Cancel running task started with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool

We have a process that starts long-running tasks via the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem command.

Each task inside, loads a new AppDomain via AppDomain.CreateDomain call, processes a bunch of stuff and exits.  Sometimes, the processing inside these apps take too long and they need to be aborted if they run for too long.

I'd like to understand if it possible to abort these threads from the outside without their knowledge so that their AppDomains are properly unloaded?

As you can see in the code below, currently the appdomain is created as a local variable, but it could be moved up to a class member if needed.  The best way for me to kill the thread is to unload that appdomain as done in the "finally" clause of the overall try/catch.  However, I'm not sure if I'll be able to access it (appdomain) "from the outside" as the AsyncExecute runs on a different thread than the aborting caller.

Here is the function that starts processing of the task:

```
public void AsyncExecute(RunningState runningState)
{
  RunningState returnedState = null;
        AppDomain runningApp = null;

        try
        {
            {

                var ads = new AppDomainSetup
                              {
                                  ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                                  DisallowBindingRedirects = false,
                                  DisallowCodeDownload = false,
                                  ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
                              };
                runningApp = AppDomain.CreateDomain("RemoteMonitor_" + runningState.LocalAccountInfo.Id, null,
                                                    ads);
                var sub =
                    runningApp.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("Processor", "Processor.ProcessorSub")
                    as ProcessorSub;
                if (sub != null)
                {
                    returnedState = sub.Run(runningState);
                }
                else
                    Logger.Instance.WriteCritical<ExecutableItem>("Cannot create Processor object");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.WriteError<ExecutableItem>(                        ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (runningApp != null)
                AppDomain.Unload(runningApp);

            if (_onCompleteHandler == null)
                Logger.Instance.WriteCritical<ExecutableItem>("Cannot complete task");
            else
                _onCompleteHandler.Invoke(returnedState);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a way to abort the `sub` object after `Run` is called?

Comment: Negative.  I can however call this: AppDomain.Unload(runningApp) to unload the whole appdomain object.  Which is my preference

Comment: That's prone to data loss and potentially leaving locks open...

Comment: Understood, but not worried about locks or data loss.  Just not sure how to call that method from "outside" of the thread

Comment: You'd have to have some way to communicate to the appdomain (via remoting handled automatically by the mashalbyref underpinnings) that you want to abort any tracked threads created with `QueueUserWorkItem` (yes, you'd have to track them too).  Otherwise you really only have the ability to unload the appdomain.  And if just unloading the appdomain isn't completely working, you might be out of luck.  Why not add an `Abort` method to `Processor.ProcessorSub`?

Answer (score 0):

One basic point, and many apologies in advance if I'm teaching how to suck eggs. Tasks submitted to the thread pool don't necessarily run straight away. They wait until one of the threads in the pool is free and then they start.

So if there's a few thread pool tasks already running when you call QueueUserWorkItem then your new task has to wait. You can tell if this is the case by logging when you call QueueUserWorkItem() and again when the first line of the try block is reached. A big time difference between those two log entries betrays the cause.

You can increase the number of threads in the thread pool.

Aborting things that are blocked is dammed hard to do cleanly in a lot of languages. The only reason you're having to do it at all, really, is because you're using a thread pool thread. However if it was a proper thread instead it wouldn't matter a jot if the task was taking ages. Assuming that the delay is down to waiting for a domain controller to respond the thread is most likely to be stuck in a blocked socket read. If so it's not consuming any processor time, and there's not much harm in having it hang around for how ever long it would naturally take for it to complete or give up on its own.